# Parse JSON Children to objects

Tags: json, vb.net

I am attempting to parse JSON children values to objects in vb.net. The below code I have been able to get first set of children objects, but I am unable to go any deeper. When it reaches subitem2 it gives me An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred.

```
Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonstring)
        Dim results As List(Of JToken) = o.Children().ToList
        For Each item As JProperty In results
            item.CreateReader()

            Dim strfname As String
            Dim strlname As String
            Dim strphone As String

            For Each subitem As JObject In item.Value
                strfname = subitem("firstname")
                strlname = subitem("lastname")
                strphone = subitem("Phone")

                For Each subitem2 As JObject In subitem("Deposits")
                    Dim id As String
                    Dim amount As String
                    id = subitem("id")
                    amount = subitem("amount")
                Next
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: Most likely you arent checking if there *is* a "Deposits" subitem.  All those variables you parse out are declared as block level vars so they wont exist outside those loops.  Generally, it seems like you should deserialize rather than parse if there are multiples of things.

Comment: @Plutonix do you have any suggestions to deserialize all the child objects? I am new to JSON.

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is months after the event, but I was just looking for some Json parsing examples and stumbled across this. In your code I notice that the two lines:

```
id = subitem("id")
amount = subitem("amount")
```

look wrong - should they not be:

```
id = subitem2("id")
amount = subitem2("amount")
```

apologies if I am way off, but thought I would point out what I thought was the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a sufficient method to do this is directly in JSON. I converted the JSON String and did it in XML. I know this isn't the most efficient way but I have a few deadlines to meet. We will be fixing later on.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
For Each subitem2 As JObject In subitem("Deposits")
  Dim id As String
  Dim amount As String
  id = subitem("id")
  amount = subitem("amount")
Next
```

with :

```
Dim id As String = ""
Dim subitem2 As List(Of JToken) = subitem("device").ToList
For Each Citem As JProperty In subitem2 
  Citem.CreateReader()
  Select Case Citem.Name
    Case "id"
      id = Citem.Value
  End Select
Next
```